# How to show warning before installing android app?

Tags: android, permissions, installation

Is it possible to show warning or licence agreement before android app installing(like showing permissions)? And how does it make?

Comment: No that is not possible. You have to display all relevant licenses which the user must agree to inside your app.

Comment: Why all the down votes? This seems like a reasonable question!

Comment: your app is not active till it is being installed. so you cannot do anything before completely installing your app

Comment: i agree with you @GHC who cares :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't interrupt Play Market install process.
What you can do:

1. Add warning, license agreement etc. at your app market
   descriprtion. Your have a special field in your apps market profile for license agreement.
2. Use special screen with warnings/agreement on the
       first run of your app. If user disagrees, just close it.